# awk field count arithmetic

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to do a simple column addition of column $i and column $((i+33)), I am not sure the syntax is correct or not.

Two files are first pasted together, and then a column addition across two files are performed.

Thank you!

```
paste DOS.tmp DOS.tmp2 | awk '{ printf "%12.8f",$1 OFS; for(i=2; i<33; i++) printf "%12.8f",$i+$((i+33)) OFS; if(33) printf "%12.8f",$33+$66; printf ORS}' >| DOS.tmp3
```

Comment: please update your Q with sample data of approx 4-6 fields across AND the required output from that input. If you know how to solve it for 6 columns, its clear you know how to solve it for your larger dataset. Good luck.

Comment: What do you think is the benefit of `$((i+33))` instead of `$(i+33)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `awk`, unlike in `bash`, variable expansion does not require a dollar sign (`$`) in front of the variable name. Variables are defined like `a = 2` and used like `print a`.

Dollar sign [(`$`) is used to refer to (input) fields](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Fields). So, `print $1` will print the first field, and `print $a` will print the field referenced by variable `a`, in our case the second field. Similarly, `print $a, $(a+3)` will print the second and fifth field (separated by the `OFS`).

All this taken together, makes your program look like:

```
awk '{ out = sprintf("%12.8f", $1)
       for (i=2; i<=33; i++) out = out sprintf("%s%12.8f", OFS, $i+$(i+33))
       print out }' numbers
```

Notice we use [`sprintf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-formatting-strings) to print all values to the output line variable `out` first, [concatenating](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Concatenation) like `out = out val`, and then printing the complete output record with `print`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to add column `i` in `file_1` and `file_2`? In this case, I provide an example:

```
paste <(seq -s' ' 33) <(seq -s' ' 33) | awk '{ for(i=1; i<=33; i++) { printf "%f",$i+$((i+33)) ; if(i!=33) printf OFS;} printf ORS}'
```